# Xamarin.Forms (Android) Bluetooth intermittently working

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

**Scenario:**

I am building an Android app using Xamarin.Forms that will be deployed to a group of devices.  All but one of the devices will be doing some data collection, and the remaining device will be the "hub" to aggregate all of the data and do some reporting.  I am using Bluetooth for the device-to-device communication.  The 'hub', labelled the master, acts as the client, and all of the collectors act as the server.  I have a prototype working with a single server and client...almost.

Occasionally the client/master will be unable to read from the server/collector.  I am struggling to find the reason for why this is and would appreciate any help.

**Symptoms:**

The client's call to .Read() from the InputStream will occasionally block indefinitely, even though the server has written to the output stream.  I've added a timeout to this call to prevent the app from getting stuck entirely. 
This happens intermittently, but I've found some pattern to when it works and when it doesn't

1. It seems to be related to the 'server' app, and not the client.  The client can remain open, running, and initiate the request to connect to the server as often as needed.
2. It always works the first time the 'server' app is launched and connected to.  It ususally works the second time.  By the third connection, .Read() will consistently block/timeout.  Closing and reopening the app on the server "cleans the slate" so to speak and it will work again.
3. Once it starts failing, it seems to be 'stuck' in a failed state.
4. Removing the app from the foreground (but not closing/killing it) seems to correct the faulted state, and the connection/read will happen successfully as long as the app/UI remains in the background.  Once restored to the foreground, it starts failing again.

**Code:**

All of the bluetooth handling is done by a single class/service that I'm injecting using Xamarin.Forms DependencyService.  All of the devices will, on startup (via the constructor of this class), loop indefinitely on a background thread, waiting for connections and repeating.  Much of this bluetooth code is based on the Bluetooth Chat example, as well as some other online resources I've found (some android native/java, some Xamarin/C#)

The master will, on demand (triggered by press of a button in the UI), attempt to connect to any collectors (via bonded bluetooth devices) and read data from them.  There is also a simple UI component which essentially serves as a console log.

Here is the service class in its entirety.

```
public class GameDataSyncService : IGameDataSyncService
{
    private const string UUID = "8e99f5f1-4a07-4268-9686-3a288326e0a2";

    private static Task acceptLoopTask;
    private static Task syncDataTask;
    private static readonly object locker = new object();
    private static bool running = false;

    public event EventHandler<DataSyncMessage> MessageBroadcast;

    public GameDataSyncService()
    {
        // Every device will listen and accept incoming connections.  The master will make the connections.
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (acceptLoopTask == null)
            {
                acceptLoopTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(AcceptLoopWorker, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SyncData()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (running)
            {
                BroadcastMessage("Previous data sync is still running.", DataSyncMessageType.Warning);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                running = true;
                syncDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(SyncDataWorker);
            }
        }
    }

    private void BroadcastMessage(string message, DataSyncMessageType type = DataSyncMessageType.Info)
    {
        MessageBroadcast?.Invoke(this, new DataSyncMessage { Text = message, Type = type });
    }

    private async Task AcceptLoopWorker()
    {
        int count = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            BluetoothSocket clientSocket = null;
            try
            {
                BroadcastMessage($"Listening for incoming connection...", DataSyncMessageType.Debug);

                serverSocket = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.ListenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(nameof(GameDataSyncService), Java.Util.UUID.FromString(UUID));
                clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept(); // This call blocks until a connection is established.
                BroadcastMessage($"Connection received from {clientSocket.RemoteDevice.Name}.  Sending data...", DataSyncMessageType.Info);

                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Hello World - {string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat(Guid.NewGuid(), ++count))}");

                await clientSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                clientSocket.OutputStream.Flush();

                // Give the master some time to close the connection from their end
                await Task.Delay(1000*3);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                BroadcastMessage($"{ex.GetType().FullName}: {ex.Message}", DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
            }
            finally
            {
                try { clientSocket?.InputStream?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.InputStream?.Dispose(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.OutputStream?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.OutputStream?.Dispose(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.Dispose(); } catch { }
                try { serverSocket?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { serverSocket?.Dispose(); } catch { }

                BroadcastMessage($"Connection closed.", DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task SyncDataWorker()
    {
        BroadcastMessage($"Beginning data sync...");

        foreach (var bondedDevice in BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BondedDevices.OrderBy(d => d.Name))
        {
            BluetoothSocket clientSocket = null;
            try
            {
                clientSocket = bondedDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString(UUID));
                BroadcastMessage($"Connecting to {bondedDevice.Name}...");
                try
                {
                    clientSocket.Connect();
                }
                catch
                {
                    BroadcastMessage($"Connection to {bondedDevice.Name} failed.", DataSyncMessageType.Error);
                }

                while (clientSocket.IsConnected)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    var readTask = clientSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (await Task.WhenAny(readTask, Task.Delay(1000)) != readTask)
                    {
                        BroadcastMessage($"Read timeout...", DataSyncMessageType.Error);
                        break;
                    }

                    int bytes = readTask.Result;
                    BroadcastMessage($"Read {bytes} bytes.", DataSyncMessageType.Success);

                    if (bytes > 0)
                    {
                        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Take(bytes).ToArray());
                        BroadcastMessage(text, DataSyncMessageType.Success);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                BroadcastMessage($"{ex.GetType().FullName}: {ex.Message}", DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
            }
            finally
            {
                try { clientSocket?.InputStream?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.InputStream?.Dispose(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.OutputStream?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.OutputStream?.Dispose(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.Close(); } catch { }
                try { clientSocket?.Dispose(); } catch { }
            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000 * 3);

        BroadcastMessage($"Data sync complete!");
        lock (locker)
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried (nothing below has had any effect):**

Most of these were from 'solutions' from other stackoverflow posts.

1. Adding arbitrary delays into the mix
2. Making sure to explicitly close/dispose everything, in order, including the streams
3. Tried replacing the socket handling with their 'Insecure' counterparts.
4. Adjusting my read timeout to something arbitrarily long, in case a second wasn't enough.
5. Disabling/Re-enabling bluetooth on the server/collector before .Accept() ing a new connection (resorted to trying random stuff by this point)

**Video:**

I took a video of this happening.
The tablet in the back is the collector/server  The tablet in the foreground is the master/client.  When the video starts, the client is displaying some previous attempts, and the server app is in the background (but running).  I demonstrate that the .Read works when the collector/server app is in the background, but not the foreground.  Each request to begin data sync has a corresponding entry to the "console" (or a warning if I pressed it too soon)
https://youtu.be/NGuGa7upCU4

**Summary:**

To the best of my knowledge, my code is correct.  I have no idea what else to change/fix to get this working more reliably. The actual connection seems like it is successful (based on logs from the server/collector, unfortunately not shown in the video), but the issue lies somewhere in the .Write (or .Read).  ANy help, suggestions, or insight would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, changed all to using:

```
private async Task AcceptLoopWorker()
{
    int count = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            BroadcastMessage("Listening for incoming connection...", DataSyncMessageType.Debug);

            using (var serverSocket = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.ListenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(nameof(GameDataSyncService), Java.Util.UUID.FromString(UUID)))
            using (var clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept()) // This call blocks until a connection is established.
            {
                BroadcastMessage(string.Format("Connection received from {0}. Sending data...", clientSocket.RemoteDevice.Name), DataSyncMessageType.Info);
                var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Hello World - {0}", string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat(Guid.NewGuid(), ++count))));
                await clientSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000 * 3); // Give the master some time to close the connection from their end
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            BroadcastMessage(string.Format("IOException {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message), DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
        {
            BroadcastMessage(string.Format("Exception {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message), DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
        }
    }
}

private async Task SyncDataWorker()
{
    BroadcastMessage("Beginning data sync...");

    foreach (var bondedDevice in BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BondedDevices.OrderBy(d => d.Name))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var clientSocket = bondedDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString(UUID)))
            {
                BroadcastMessage(string.Format("Connecting to {0}...", bondedDevice.Name));

                if (!clientSocket.IsConnected)
                {
                    clientSocket.Connect();
                }

                if (clientSocket.IsConnected)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    var readTask = clientSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (await Task.WhenAny(readTask, Task.Delay(1000)) != readTask)
                    {
                        BroadcastMessage("Read timeout...", DataSyncMessageType.Error);
                        break;
                    }

                    int bytes = readTask.Result;
                    BroadcastMessage(string.Format("Read {0} bytes.", bytes), DataSyncMessageType.Success);

                    if (bytes > 0)
                    {
                        var text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Take(bytes).ToArray());
                        BroadcastMessage(text, DataSyncMessageType.Success);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    BroadcastMessage("Not Connected...", DataSyncMessageType.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            BroadcastMessage(string.Format("IOException {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message), DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
        {
            BroadcastMessage(string.Format("Exception {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message), DataSyncMessageType.Debug);
        }
    }

    await Task.Delay(1000 * 3);

    BroadcastMessage("Data sync complete!");
    lock (locker)
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```